# Error "no matching function for call to 'LGame::LGame(String&)'" if in child class there is no constructor method

Tags: c++, arduino

Something happens, i can't understand.

There is a class called Game, and it has constructor

```
class Game
{
  public:

    Game(String& _name){
      clientID = _name;
    }
}

class LGame: public Game{
  public:

  // ...another code
}
```

I call

```
String myName = "balls3"; //name of module
LGame game(myName);
```

and there is error `error: no matching function for call to 'LGame::LGame(String&)'`

But if I add same constructor in child class, everything work

```
class LGame
{
  public:

    LGame(String& _name){
      clientID = _name;
    }
```

// ...another code
    }

what i am doing wrong. I am new in Arduino/C++

Comment: What is unclear? The child class does not have an appropriate constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is - this is the way C++ works :)
Long answer:
When you declare a class in C++ it creates a default constructor for this class if possible. 
The way you have defined `class Game` - it has a non-default constructor. That is - an instance of class Game can only be created by passing a value of String:

```cpp
String a{...};
Game game{a};
```

All classes derived from `class Game` must call `Game::Game(String& )` constructor in order to initialize it.

So your derived class LGame can not be created as it requires initialization of `Game` fist.

But class LGame does not declare a constructor.

When you define a new class `class LGame` by default C++ 'attempts' to create a default constructor for you `LGame::LGame()`. In this case - it can not be done because `Game` class has a non-default constructor that you have defined. You need to explicitly tell the compiler how to create initialize an instance of LGame - that is you need to define constructor explicitly:

```cpp
class LGame: public Game{
public: 
  LGame(String const& s): Game{s} 
  {...}
...
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for great answer. Is there easy way to change for example Game class to not redefine same method in childs?
Yes problem is in my python/php/js way minding :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In your example, `Game` is the base class. It does not 'redefine' anything :) LGame is derived class and inherits from `Game`. So - whatever methods `Game` has in public section - will be available to users of `LGame` class.